# AWS CDK multi stack or single stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I use CDK to deploy a lambda function (along some IAM role & queue) and monitoring resources about the lambda, lambda log group and queue earlier. What i have right now is basically 2 class, 1 class to create all the lambda related resource and another to create monitoring resource and they are added all into 1 deployment stack.

Recently im deploying this to a new account and i realized my stack fail to create because some of the monitoring stuff is looking for the lambda log group and cant find it since its not created yet.

So what is the better option:

1. have 2 deployment group, 1 for lambda related resource and 1 for monitoring resource
2. use [dependencies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/core-readme.html#dependencies) to create some ordering in my stack.

seems like both possible solution but what is a better long term solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "class" (perhaps `cdk.Construct` subclasses grouping your resources?) and "deployment group" (`cdk.Stack`?).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean a Stack for your two classes, then you are better off making  them both `cdk.NestedStack`s and instantiating them in a single common stack. You can then expose constructs as class attributes in one stack and pass them into the other as parameters to the second. Of course, this only works one way - if you have to go both ways you need to re-evaluate how you have your stacks organized.

The advantage of doing this is great: exposing constructs as an attribute is the best practice as it gives you direct access to that construct before it creates the CloudFormation data for it. you have complete access to every part of that construct from various arns (like dynamodb stream arns which are difficult to import) and automatically know the layer versions for lamdba layers - among many other things.

In addition, you never run into a stack dependency - if they are different top level stacks and you share constructs between them you can very run into lock situations where attempting to change something in one stack creates a dependency lock and prevents the stack from deploying.

The downside is that they all are part of the deployment. So there is a potential for something to be updated when you didnt expect it too - though CDK does use the Cloudformation Changeset system so it should not update things that have no changes applied to them (but sometimes, changes occur because of the way CDK generates tokens and such that you may not be aware of)

IF you do not go this route you are stuck using the various `from*` methods in cdk constructs to import the existing construct into your stack. This causes some issues, as it it can't import everything about a given construct at synth time (layer version and dynamo stream arns are two notable ones i mentioned already). Plus, you need to know the name of the construct - and Best Practices says you shouldn't deliberately name your constructs so you can easily spin up adhoc versions of your app without naming issues.